# grouping based on same columid in mysql php

Tags: mysql

i am working on file uploading project in which file uploading was sucessful.

Now i am looking for displaying my uploads table which is used to store details of uploaded files is like:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+-----------+
|    projectId       |  filename          |  projectDetails  |ProjectName |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+
|   pid1             | admin.zip          |  This Is A Test  |myProject   |
|   pid1             | admin1.zip         |  This Is A Test  |myProject   |
|   pid2             | admin2.zip         |  This Is A Test2 |myProject2  |
|   pid2             | admin3.zip         |  This Is A Test2 |myProject2  |
|   pid1             | admin4.zip         |  This Is A Test  |myProject   |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+
```

can i know that can i get an output like

```
 +--------------------+--------------------+------------------+-----------+
|    projectId       |  filename          |  projectDetails  |ProjectName |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+
|   pid1             | admin.zip          |  This Is A Test  |myProject   |
|                    | admin1.zip         |                  |            |
|                    | admin4.zip         |                  |            |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+
```

Comment: It's all about representation of data. There's nothing to do in `MySQL` end.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what about using this query :

```
select projectId, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct filename) as filename, projectDetails, ProjectName
from yourtable 
group by pid1
```

Comment: yes it worked i get what i am looking for you are awsome

Comment: @shahidkhan Be aware that this returns arbitrary projectDetails and ProjectName.

Comment: how can i avoid this